# What is happening behind the scenes, with the commits and HEAD while trying to git reset --soft and undoing it?

Tags: git, github, git-reset, git-merge-conflict

I Issued `git reset --soft HEAD~1` then I decided not to do this, I want to go back to my previous state.

So, I searched in Stack Overflow, then I got this answer:

> Now I just want to go back to the time before I issued the reset
>
> If you only want to cancel the git reset --soft you just did, you can look up the former HEAD commit id in the reflogs
>
> ```
> $ git reflog
> $ git reset --soft formerCommit
> ```

I issued the `git reset --soft formerCommit` as mentioned. Then I checked the HEAD using `git reflog`--

[image]

It created two more logs as you can see, but my head is at the required commit. So, I thought if I make new changes and push it, it will just work fine.

But no, I got this error (**pushed after making a new change**)--

```
$ git push
To https://github.com/Arpan619Banerjee/Forkify_JS_app.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Arpan619Banerjee/Forkify_JS_app.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Though `git log` do not show those two extra logs shown in `git reflog`

[image]

**So, now my questions are** ---

1. What is the correct way to revert changes in some files(not all the files previously committed) and push it again?
2. What is the advantage of using the commands that I issued in the question while resetting if I have to force the push?
3. After issuing `git reset --soft HEAD~1` , I could have `unstaged` the changes> made new changes>commited> forced the push.
4. Why do I always need to force the changes? I understand that the `Heads` have diverged, but isn't there any other way to **gracefully** do this?

How can I understand the concepts, I am new to git and self learning it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, direct (although not all that useful) answers to your direct questions:

> 1. What is the correct way to revert changes in some files(not all the files previously committed) and push it again?

There isn't one.  That is, there is no *one single correct way* to do this.  There are many *different* correct ways to do this.

> 2. What is the advantage of using [`git reset --soft`] if I have to force the push?

If this produces the commit graph you like, that's a way to produce the commit graph you like.

> 3. After issuing `git reset --soft HEAD~1`, I could have `unstaged` the changes> made new changes>commited> forced the push.

This is not a question.  It is a statement (and a true one).

> 4. Why do I always need to force the [push]?

You don't *always* need to; you do for these cases because you're deliberately asking some *other* Git repository to *throw away some commit(s)*.

#### Key concepts

> How can I understand the concepts?

The key here is that Git is not really about files—though it stores files—nor about branch names, though it uses branch names.  Git is really about *commits*.

Each commit stores files.  In fact, each commit stores a *complete snapshot of all files*.  The files inside these snapshots, however, are in a special, read-only, compressed and de-duplicated format, that only Git itself understands.  None of the other software on your system can make any sense of these files.  (Note that the de-duplication means that it's OK that every commit stores a copy of *every* file, because most commits just re-use most of the files from some other commit, so that these multiple copies take almost no extra space.)

It's important to remember that *nothing about any commit can ever be changed* after the commit is made.  In other words, all commits are completely, totally read-only.  (This is actually a general property of all internal Git objects and it ties in to their object hash IDs.)

But if commits are read-only, and only Git can read the files, how do we ever *use* them?  We need ordinary files.  We need to be able to read them!  We need to be able to **write** to them!  So to *use* Git, we have to take the files *out* of Git.  This is what `git checkout`—or in Git 2.23 or later, `git switch`—is for: to locate some particular commit and *extract* it.  Note that Git will *find* the commit by its hash ID, even if we use a *branch name* like `master`.  We'll get into this a bit more in a moment.

Before we dive into that, though, we should look at exactly what a commit does for you, because there are two parts to each commit:

- A commit has a full snapshot of all your files.  That's its main data: a full copy of every file you told Git to save, at the time you told Git to save it, in the form it had in Git at that time.
- A commit also has *metadata*, such as the name of the person who made it.  Most of this metadata is the stuff you see in `git log` output: someone's name and email address, a date-and-time-stamp, and a log message, for instance.  But one piece of metadata is crucial for Git itself.  Each commit stores the raw hash ID of its immediate *parent* commit, or for a merge commits, its parents (plural).

Most commits have just one parent.  If we have a chain of such commits, we can draw them like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where each letter stands in for some actual commit hash ID.  Commit `H` is simply the *last* commit in the chain.  Because we used commit `G` to *make* commit `H`, commit `H` itself remembers commit `G`'s hash ID, in its metadata, as its parent.

We say that commit `H` *points to* commit `G`.  Note that these arrows always point backwards.  They have to, because *everything* inside a commit is read-only.  But commit `G` also points backwards, to commit `F`: `G`'s parent is `F`.  And of course commit `F` points backwards as well, to yet another earlier commit.

What this means for us is that if we can just remember the hash ID of the *last* commit in some chain of commits like this, we can use that commit to find *all the earlier commits*.  Git now has a clever trick:  **A branch name like `master` simply holds the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.**

#### Building a new commit

So, suppose we have a tiny repository with just three commits in it.  We'll call these commits `A`, `B`, and `C` and draw them like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

I get lazy here (for a reason) and don't draw the commit arrows as backwards-pointing arrows, but we do have to remember that they only go backwards.  That is, if we have commit `B`, we can't easily go *forwards* to `C`, but we can easily to *backwards* to `A`.

To build a new commit, we start by having Git extract one of our existing commits.  Let's pick commit `C`, by using the *name* `master`.  Git extracts commit `C` somewhere—we'll get into this more in a bit—and lets us see and work with all of its files.  We'll need to *stage* and *commit* too, and we'll go into that more in a bit as well.  But one way or another we will make a *new* commit, which gets a new, unique hash ID.

The new hash ID looks random.  It isn't random at all: it's actually a cryptographic checksum of all of the commit's contents.  It depends on every bit of every file saved *in* that commit, and every bit in all of the metadata for that commit, including your name, the date-and-time when you make it, and the parent hash ID.  But it's way too hard to predict: you'd need to know all of this *and* the exact second at which you're going to make the commit, in order to predict the hash ID.  So it *looks* random, and we'll just pretend it is for now.  Because the new hash ID is big and ugly and random-looking, we'll just call it `D`.

Git makes commit `D` so that it points back to existing commit `C`, like this:

```
A--B--C
       \
        D
```

Now comes the trick: because `D` is the *last* commit in the chain, **Git stores `D`'s actual hash ID into the name `master`.**  The name moves!  The name now points to the new commit:

```
A--B--C
       \
        D   <-- master
```

Now, we can have more than one branch name, pointing the same commit.  Suppose we made a new branch *name* `dev` first, so that we start out with this:

```
A--B--C   <-- dev, master
```

If we pick branch `dev` to use, we pick commit `C`.  If we pick branch `master` to use, we *still* pick commit `C`.  Both names point to `C` right now, so either way we get commit `C`.  The difference is what happens when we make a *new* commit.

If we tell Git that we'd like to use the name `dev`—if we `git checkout dev` or `git switch dev`—then we start out with this:

```
A--B--C   <-- dev (HEAD), master
```

That is, Git attaches this special name `HEAD` to *one* (and only one) branch name.  Then when we *do* make new commit `D`, *that's the name that Git updates*.  So this time, we'll have:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

#### We can add and delete branch names any time we like

Suppose we have:

```
A--B--C   <-- master (HEAD)
       \
        D   <-- dev
```

That is, we *made* commit `D` while on `dev`, but then ran `git checkout master` or `git switch master` to go back to previous commit `C`.  Our `HEAD` is now attached to the name `master`.

Suppose we now tell Git: *delete the name `dev`*.  We'll have to force Git to do this, with:

```
git branch --force --delete dev
```

or:

```
git branch -D dev
```

(older versions of Git require the uppercase `-D` option here as `git branch` once did not to know how to use `--force` with `--delete`).  The result is this:

```
A--B--C   <-- master (HEAD)
       \
        D   ???
```

Commit `D` *is still in the repository* for a while, and if we know its hash ID, we can find it.  But *Git* finds commits by branch name, so now *Git* can't find commit `D` for us—except, that is, via Git's *reflogs*.

I won't go into a lot of detail here, but there is one reflog for each branch name, plus one more for `HEAD` itself.  When you have Git delete a branch name like `dev`, this also deletes its reflog.<sup>1</sup>  Fortunately, if you were *on* the branch—had used `git checkout` or `git switch` to get to it—recently, the `HEAD` reflog will store the hash ID.  Note that reflog entries eventually *expire* and get discarded, and server Gits—the ones you `git push` to—usually don't even have reflogs.

---

<sup>1</sup>This deletion of the reflog is almost certainly a mistake, that Git has lived with for 15 years.  It may someday be fixed, especially if Git acquires real database software for its name-to-value key-value store.  This would allow undeleting a branch name.

---

#### Names—and other commits that Git can find—are how Git *finds* commits

We mentioned earlier that branch names hold the hash ID of the *last* commit in a chain.  For instance, we can have:

```
          I--J   <-- branch2
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K   <-- branch3
```

Here, commit `J` is the *last* commit on `branch2`.  Commit `K` is the *last* commit on `branch3`.  Commit `H` is on *all three branches* but is the *last* commit on `master`.

Commit `G` can be found in any of three ways:

- start at `master` and step back once, or
- start at `branch2` and then step back three times (`J`, then `I`, `H`, `G`), or
- start at `branch3` and then step back twice (`K`, `H`, `G`).

If we ignore the reflogs, these are the three ways to find `G`, but there is only one way to find `I`, `J`, or `K`.  If we delete the names `branch2` and/or `branch3`, those commits won't be find-able.

Git will *eventually* discard un-find-able commits.  In your own repository, this takes longer because the reflogs are there and act as an alternative way to find the commits.  In a server repository, there aren't any reflogs and the commits will generally expire within just two weeks.<sup>2</sup>

We can safely delete the *name* `master`, though, as long as we keep at least one of the other two names, because Git will keep `H` around as long as it can find `J` by the name `branch2` and then find `I` and then find `H`, for instance.

---

<sup>2</sup>The two week grace period gives Git some time to get them properly named: various operations in Git create objects first, *then* adjust the names to be able to find them.  So Git's cleanup / garbage-collection process has to give other Git commands a little bit of time to get their work done.

---

#### We can forcibly move a name any time we like

Suppose we have:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

and then we make a new commit `I` on master:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Now suppose we decide we don't like something about commit `I`.  Maybe one of its snapshot files is wrong.  Maybe we misspelled a word in our `git log` message.  We can make Git move the *name* `master` back one step, using `git reset`, like this:

```
          I   ???
         /
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Where is commit `I`?  It's still there, in the repository.  We can find its raw hash ID in `git reflog`, if we like, because our Git has reflogs.  But we can't find it using the *name* `master`, because `master` points to `H`, not `I`, now.  We can't find it using commit `H`, because `H` points *backwards*, to commit `G`, not forwards to `I`.

This is one of three things that `git reset` often does: it moves the *branch name* to which `HEAD` is attached.  Note: the `git reset` command is very big and complicated and this answer is only going to talk about a few of its many jobs.

We can also use the `git branch` command, with the `--force` flag, to move any branch name to point to any commit.  Well, *almost* any branch name: `git branch` will refuse to move the *name* we're using right now by having it checked-out.  That is, if `HEAD` is attached to `master`, we can move any branch name *except* `master`, using `git branch`.<sup>3</sup>  There's a reason for this, and it has to do with Git's *index* and your *work-tree*.

---

<sup>3</sup>If you use `git worktree add` to create extra work-trees, they each have their own `HEAD`.  This will "lock down" other branch names like this.

---

#### Git's index and your work-tree

We noted several times so far that *commits* are read-only and must be extracted.  The extracted files are easy to comprehend: they're just ordinary files.  They live in an area that Git calls your *working tree* or *work-tree*.

A standard (non-server, non-"bare") repository comes with a work-tree.  The work-tree is not actually *in* the repository: all of the stuff that makes up the repository is in the `.git` directory / folder.  The `.git` folder is usually at the top level of the work-tree, so they're almost side-by-side.  People tend to think of these as a pair, and they *work* as a pair, but your work-tree is *yours*. You're allowed to mess with it as much as you like.  It's the stuff in the `.git` folder that's Git's, that you should not mess with, in general.

So, when you pick a commit—using `git checkout master` or `git switch dev`, for instance—to have and work on / with, Git will copy the *committed* files, which are saved *in* the commit, to your work-tree.  The committed files are all read-only, and are saved for all time, or at least, for as long as the commit itself continues to exist.  As long as Git can *find* the commit, its files are safely saved forever—well, provided you don't mess with Git's files in `.git`, and your laptop doesn't [catch fire](https://www.google.com/search?q=flaming+laptop) or whatever.

This would be a nice simple picture—Git has its commits, and your work-tree has the files you'll use to make the next commit—but it's wrong in an important but subtle way.  **Git doesn't actually make *new* commits from your work-tree!**

We noted earlier that the files inside a Git commit are in a special, Git-only, frozen and de-duplicated form.  To go along with that, and to make its own job much easier, when you *extract* a commit, Git copies the committed files to a sort of holding area that Git calls its *index* or *staging area*.<sup>3</sup>  So this means that Git has not two, but *three* copies of each file.  If you have, in your commit, a file named `README.md`, Git has three `README.md` files:

- `git show HEAD:README.md`: this is the committed copy.  It can't be changed.  You can make a new commit, or check out some other commit, to select some *other* committed copy, but like all committed copies, it is frozen for all time.
- `git show :README.md`: this is the *index* or *staging area* copy.  It *can* be changed!  It's in the frozen *format*, but you can replace it wholesale using `git add`, or even remove it entirely.
- `README.md` (just a regular file): this is *your* copy in *your work-tree*.  You can do whatever you like with it.

These are the three important copies of each file.  When you run `git commit`, Git will make its *new* commit by packaging up all the *index* copies.  Those become new snapshots, which live forever, or at least, live as long as you and Git can *find* the commit's hash ID.

Until you make a commit, the index and work-tree copies of the file are just temporary, though.  They can be replaced or removed!  They are not permanent like committed copies.  The one in your work-tree isn't even *in* Git, in most senses.  (The staged one is kind of halfway-into Git.)

**Note that there is a staged copy of every file,** not just files you have just `git add`-ed.  What `git add` does is *replace* the staged copy with an update from your work-tree.  If you modify the work-tree copy, then update the staged copy, now the staged copy *doesn't match* the `HEAD` copy.  If you un-modify the work-tree copy and stage again, now the staged copy *does* match the `HEAD` copy again.

---

<sup>3</sup>Technically, what's in the index / staging-area is not a *copy* of each file, but rather information *about* the file: its name, its mode, and an internal Git *blob hash ID*.  The snapshot is stored as an internal Git *blob object*.  But Git handles all of this invisibly for you, and for the most part, you can just think of the index as holding a copy of the file, in Git's frozen format.  The only time this breaks down is if you use `git ls-files --stage` or `git update-index` to deal with Git at an extra-low level.

---

#### `git status` runs two comparisons

When you use `git status`—which is a good idea; it tells you a lot of useful stuff—it actually runs *two* compare operations:

- First, it compares the `HEAD` commit to the index.  For each file that is the same, Git says nothing.  For each file that is *different*, Git says *staged for commit*.
- Then it compares the index to your work-tree.  For each file that is the same, Git says nothing.  For each file that is *different*, Git says *not staged for commit*.

Files that are in your work-tree, but not in Git's index, are a bit of a special case: they are called *untracked*.  We won't go into more detail here, but note that the set of files that is in Git's index changes, as you `git add` or `git rm` files, and it changes when you use `git checkout` or `git switch` to extract some other commit.  So whether a file is tracked or untracked depends on what's in Git's index *right now*, and you can change that.

Sometimes, changing what's in the index also tells Git to overwrite your work-tree in some way, too, though.  That's particularly true for `git checkout`, since it has to fill in *both* Git's index *and* your work-tree.  But it's also true for `git reset`, depending on how you run it.

#### Your kind of `git reset` is about doing 1, 2, or 3 things

The `git reset` command is big and we won't talk about all of it, but the kind of reset you're doing:

```
git reset --soft <hash>
```

uses a version of `git reset` that does up to three things:

1. It can move a *branch name*.  You pick a commit hash ID—by name, or by cutting and pasting an actual hash ID, for instance—and you are telling Git: *move the current branch name, to which `HEAD` is attached, so that it points to that commit*.
2. It can erase-and-reload Git's index.  Again, you pick a commit, and Git will load its own index from that commit.  Files that were in the index before, now aren't any more.  The files that are in the index now are the ones from that commit.
3. And, it can erase-and-reload your work-tree.  Any work-tree files that were in the index, but should not be in the index at all, will be removed; any work-tree files that need to be changed in the index will be replaced in your work-tree; and for any files that are in the commit you're moving to, but weren't in Git's index before, Git will copy those files into its index and your work-tree.

That last step—of updating your work-tree—only happens if you *tell* Git to do it, using `git reset --hard`.  With the default `git reset --mixed`, Git will only do steps 1 and 2.  If you use `git reset --soft`, Git will only do step 1.

Note that Git will always do step 1—it will always *move* the current branch—but you can pick the *current commit* as the commit to move to.  That is, if your current branch name currently names commit `H`, and you say `git reset --hard hash-of-H`, the name "moves" so that it now points to commit `H`, just like it did before.  So that's what `git reset --hard`, with no commit hash ID, is for: it "moves" the branch without moving it, but then also resets Git's index and resets your work-tree.

The `git reset --soft` variant makes Git do step 1—move the name—and then stop.  So this only makes any sense if you are planning to really move the name.  You pick a new commit hash ID, and the current *name* moves there, with no other changes.

If you have:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- master (HEAD)
```

and you use `git reset --soft hash-of-H`, you get:

```
          I
         /
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Git's index and your work-tree are unchanged, so you can now run `git commit` and make a *new* commit.  If you like, you can edit files and `git add` them, to update your work-tree and copy the update into Git's index first.  Either way you can make a new commit with a new date-and-time and maybe a different log message:

```
          I
         /
...--G--H--J   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Because `J` is a different *commit*, it has a different hash ID.

#### `git push` is about changing things in some other Git

This brings us to `git push`.  It's all well and good to make changes in *your* Git repository, by adding and maybe removing (or shoving aside) some commits and moving various branch names around.  But that only affects *your* repository.  There's some other set of Git repositories and you might like to make changes to them as well.

If you can log in on those machines, you can make commits there.  But the commits you make there will be made at a different time, and will have different hash IDs—and maybe you *can't* log in on those machines anyway.  For instance, maybe that other repository is on GitHub.

Fortunately, Git has `git push` as a built in operation.  This has your Git call up some other Git.  Your Git and their Git will then have a conversation of sorts.<sup>4</sup>  Your Git will list, for their Git, some commit hash ID.  Their Git can look at their repository and see if they have that hash ID.  If they do, they have that commit now.  If not, they *don't* have that commit, and your Git will send it.  Your Git is then obligated to offer the commit's parent(s), too, and will send it / them as needed, and their parents, and so on.

The result of all of this is that if *they* have:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- master
```

in *their* repository, and you have:

```
          I
         /
...--G--H--J--K--L   <-- master (HEAD)
```

your Git will offer `L` and they will say *please send it* and your Git will offer and send `K` and `J` as well, and offer `H` but they'll say *no thanks, I already have that one*.

So, by this process, your Git sends to them any commits that they *don't have but will need*.  Then your Git sends some final requests, or—if you use the force option—commands: *If it's OK, please set your `master` to point to commit `L`* or *Set your `master` to point to commit `L`!*

If they obey this polite request or command, *they* will now have:

```
          I
         /
...--G--H--J--K--L   <-- master
```

just like you do.  But *they do not have any reflogs*.  So they won't be able to *find* commit `I`!  Their Git will remove commit `I` pretty fast—not right away, but it won't be safe for at least a month, like yours will.

If you don't use `--force`, their Git will say: *No, if I set my `master` to point to `L`, I'll lose some commit(s) off my `master`.*  They don't even check to see if some other branch name protects commit `I`.  They just say *no*.  Your Git tells you about this by printing the *non-fast-forward* error.

---

<sup>4</sup>Note that the closest thing there is to the opposite of `push` is actually `git fetch`, which also has a conversation with the other Git.  The difference is that with this conversation, your Git *gets* things from their Git.  It ends with your Git updating your *remote-tracking names*.

The `git pull` command, which might seem like the opposite, isn't: it means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command*—often `git merge`.  The `git push` command doesn't run any second Git command; it never does any merging.

---

#### Another way to get what you might want

What if you have:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- master
```

and you don't like the arrangement of some file(s) in `I`?  Well, that's not really a problem.  You don't have to *remove* `I` from this chain.  Just check out `master`, so that it's the `HEAD` commit and you have all the files active as usual:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- master (HEAD)
```

and then change your work-tree and index so that it contains the files you would like.  You can get some file(s) from commit `H`, or from commit `G`, directly.  In Git 2.23 or later, you can use the `git restore` command to do this:

```
git restore --source=<hash-of-G> --staged --worktree path/to/file.ext
```

This copies the *committed* `path/to/file.ext` file out of commit `G`, into both the index / staging-area (`--staged`) and your work-tree (`--worktree`).

If your Git is older than Git 2.23, you can do this with the `git checkout` command—the `git checkout` command is at least two commands rolled into one.<sup>5</sup>  So in older Git, or if you have this as a habit already, you can do:

```
git checkout <hash-of-G> -- path/to/file.ext
```

which copies the file to both Git's index and your work-tree, just like `git restore`.<sup>6</sup>

In any case, once you have updated your index and work-tree to have what you'd like them to have, you can run `git commit` to make a new commit:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
```

New commit `J` holds the snapshot you want, and has whatever log message you choose to put in.  Its parent is existing commit `I`.  You can now call up some other Git and send over new commit `J` to add on to *their* `master`, which in *their* `repository` points to the (identical to yours and therefore same hash ID) commit `I`.  This *adds to* their `master`, without dropping any commits, so they will take this `git push` without complaint.<sup>7</sup>

---

<sup>5</sup>In Git 2.23, the Git folks finally acknowledged that `git checkout` has too many jobs, and split them up.  Someday, perhaps, they might do this for other commands like `git reset`—though in fact, `git restore` takes on a lot of what you can do with `git reset`, and would allow `git reset` to be smaller command.  But Git tries to keep its commands backwards-compatible through upgrades, so `git checkout` still works, and `git reset` can't be trimmed back.

<sup>6</sup>Unlike `git restore`, you *cannot* choose to have the file go into just one of these two places—not using `git checkout` anyway.

<sup>7</sup>On GitHub, where you can set some branches to be *protected*, this requires that the branch not be "protected", or that GitHub have been told that you have administrative privileges and can `git push` to a protected branch.  Protected branches are not built in to Git itself: they're an add-on.  Most web hosting sites seem to have added them on by now, though.